# How to extract specific part of Yaml depending on a condition?

Tags: php, yaml

In the following yaml text to retrieve the names of children *where exposed is true* ?

***INPUT***

```
parent:
  child1:
    units:
        machine: 1
        name: Cathy
        relation: daughter
        boolean: true
  child2:
    exposed: true
    units:
        machine: 2
        name: Peter
        relation: son
        boolean: false
```

***EXPECTED OUTPUT***

Peter

***CURRENT CODE***

```
//input
$yaml = <<<EOD
parent:
  child1:
    units:
        name: Cathy
        relation: daughter
  child2:
    exposed: true
    units:
        name: Peter
        relation: son
EOD;

//convert to array
$parsed = yaml_parse($yaml);

//get all values from specific key in a multidimensional array
var_dump(array_value_recursive('name', $parsed));


/**
 * Get all values from specific key in a multidimensional array
 *
 * @param $key string
 * @param $arr array
 * @return null|string|array
 */
function array_value_recursive($key, array $arr){
    $val = array();
    array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k) use($key, &$val){
        if($k == $key) array_push($val, $v);
    });
    return count($val) > 1 ? $val : array_pop($val);
}
```

***CURRENT OUTPUT***

Cathy
Peter

In the above output, Cathy is the unwanted entry.
Correct output should be Peter.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't see anywhere `exposed=true` clause.

You are walking the array and searching for the `name` key, if you find it you push it to an array. You are missing an additional `if (exposed == true)..`

It is only logical you will get an array of all entries.